# How to create a single API which takes data of all Employees

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to django. I have a model like this:

```
class Standup(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey("Team", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    standup_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class StandupUpdate(models.Model):
    standup = models.ForeignKey("Standup", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey("Employee", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    work_done_yesterday = models.TextField()
    work_to_do = models.TextField()
    blockers = models.TextField()
```

If I write view for this model, every employee will have to hit API for his/her standup update. But I am supposed create a single API which takes updates of all the employees and saves it into database. In frontend, it will be something like this:

- Employee will select on a team as one employee can be a part of
  multiple teams.
- Then the employee will give his/her stadup updates.
- Then another employee will do the same thing and so on.
- At the end,by clicking on submit button, whole data will be saved together.
  Any guidance on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need a separate model for Updates.

I would try to approach it like that:

- make the Standup model reference both Team and Employee models;
- last_update, status, work_to_do etc. as its fields;
- make a custom serializer that accepts a list with Standup field values and takes the authorized user's ID from request object's data. last_update time can be now(), status calculated according to your business logic

[This](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) part of DRF documentation could probably be helpful.